# Excluding participants in r

Tags: r

I have quite a large dataset. I would like to exclude people who have certain conditions.

In other words, I want to drop rows that have answered yes to the question.

How do I do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done it using `data.table` pakage in R,

If you have a data with the column "yes" and "no" and wanted to remove those rows with "yes", you can try this

```
df <- data.table(A=seq(1:5),B=c("yes","yes","no","no","no"))
df
A   B
1: 1 yes
2: 2 yes
3: 3  no
4: 4  no
5: 5  no
df[!B=="yes",]
A  B
1: 3 no
2: 4 no
3: 5 no
```

Hope it will serve your purpose.

Comment: thank you the code works but it is removing the nas too which I would like to keep.

Comment: can you show me your sample dataset, then it would have been easy for me to understand

Answer (score -1):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix`.  If the whole dataset includes columns with 'yes', 'no' values, convert the dataset to a logical matrix `df1 == 'yes'`, get the `rowSums`, check if it is equal to 0 i.e. the row doesn't haven't any 'yes', use that to subset the rows

```
df1[rowSums(df1 == 'yes', na.rm = TRUE) == 0,]
```

---

If it is a single column, use `subset`

```
 subset(df1, col1 == "yes")
```